# SimpleTransformers tokenization with [CLS] and [SEP]

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, simpletransformers

I understand that simpleTransformers offers a simpler API, so we don't have to tokenize our data prior to training and it is done automatically based on the model we select,

But I was wondering, how is it done and how can I manipulate it?

In the case of binary classification, if I have 1 sentence then it is simply:

> [CLS] This is my original sentence.

What if I want to add another 2 sentences, we have 2 options either:

> Option 1: [CLS] This is my original sentence. [SEP] This is my 1st
> extra sentence. [SEP] This is my 2nd extra sentence
>
> Option 2: [CLS] This is my original sentence. This is my 1st extra
> sentence. This is my 2nd extra sentence

Usually transformer model would learn better from option 1, but since simpleTransformer does it automatically, I was wondering how do I ensure that I am doing option 1?